# Monitor clicks/goals Google Analytics with iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, tracking, statistics

We've got a site that shows some content in iframes loaded from another domains. What I'd like to do is setup some Goals to track if this stuff is clicked, is this possible to track these clicks?

I know that this content us outside our domain but is it still in the dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Since Goal Tracking is Profile based, the key is to have a tracking of all domains into one Profile. See the *[How do I install the tracking code if my site spans multiple domains?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503)* entry in the Google Analytics Help for further instructions. After that your iframe contents will appear as usual PageViews in the reports. (For instance, if you used `<iframe src="http://otherdomain.com/stuff"></iframe>`, you will find PageViews for ’/stuff’.)

Otherwise, I don't really know what you mean under ’stuff is clicked’. If it's an object in the iframe you want to track, you may generate a virtual PageView when visitor clicks on it:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("/Stuff_clicked");
```

Comment: That link is no longer found which is a pitty as I'm trying to find information about goals/sales/conversion inside an iFrame which is on a different domain than the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to install GATC (Google Analytics Tracking Code) on so called another domains which you are loading inside your iFrame, unfortunately, you won't be able to track any clicks or virtual page-views for those domains. Any clicks or event occurring on any domain can be tracked back to your account as far as your GATC which includes your Google Analytics ProfileID e.g. UA-XXXX-X is installed on that page.